# subframe in contentscript of chrome extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I inject my js codes to all subframes using

```
"all_frames": true
```

in manifest.json.
Now for some specific reason, I need to do something in top frame only. Instead of injecting another js with

```
"all_frames": false
```

is there anyway to know if current frame is top frame or not when all frames are injected?

Comment: `if (window === top)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), window===top works.